# Parse a hexadevimal value, convert it to a string representation and get its real value back in c++

Tags: c++

I try to implement some kind of scripting language and i can already parse "words" and "decimal numbers"

```
a = 10; <-- numbers only have digits
b = 3.14; <-- also decimals except they have exactly 1 dot
c = "Hello"; <-- strings are in double quotes
```

But now i want to parse hexadecimals.

```
d = 'A0'; <-- Hexadecimals would be in single quotes
```

Decimals are easy, they only contain numbers, also decimals except they can have exactly 1 dot. So i thought i could parse "other number formats" using a prefix like

```
h10 (hex)
o10 (octal)
```

I parse a text char by char and look for predefined token characteristics to build an AST. All "variables" are converted to strings representing them and a tag what type it really is. For example if an assignments "result" is 10, i build a string and another variable to hold its datatype

```
std::string value = "10"; <-- 10
std::string type = "Integer"; <-- as Integer
```

to pass it around the lexer, the parser and the interpreter. In the script they has to be declared like

```
a = 1;
b = 3.14;
c = 'C0';
```

so the parser would do

```
    | parser found the first -> ' <-
a = 'A';
     | now start reading char/digit by char/digit, the first is the highest
a = 'ABC';
        | until there is no -> ' <- again
a = 'ABC';
```

and create tokens where all values are stored as a string regardless of what it was

```
// pseudo code
Token { type="Integer", value="1" }
Token { type="Decimal", value="3.14" }
Token { type="Hex", value="C0" }
```

Hexadecimals are the only datatype enclosed by `''`. 
When i "interpret" a single addition of two tokens i do an if else statement using the `Token.type()` and make the (unary/binary) addition converting the `Token.value()` to an Integer or Double.
Strings are just concatenated for writing functions. 
I hope this is enough information.

My problems/questions are

- how do i correctly parse the hexadecimal values in the textfile like
  " a = 'ABC'; " and build the hexadecimal and Integer value of it?
- how to convert the real value to a string and back for display/calculation?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell more on this: `Hexadecimals are the only datatype enclosed by ''`. Why so? Why can't octal number have that?

Comment: I just thought its easier to select for parsing. Of course octal can also have it. Its not the problem. The problem is the parsing.

Comment: How will you differentiate between octal and decimal number then?

Comment: I wrote it in the question.. a decimal have maximal 1 dot and all numbers

Comment: So, Ultimately, you will have `h` prefix for hex and `o` prefix for octal. Right?

Comment: I could but thats not the problem/question. until now my language only has integers and strings - edit: and decimals

Comment: Please elaborate on the issue that you are facing.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. The last 2 sentences are my questions.. Thats not too hard.

Comment: I saw that. But that's easy right. The way you do it for `octal`, you can do the same for `hex` also.

Comment: But you need to have some way during your parsing to differentiate between `string` and `hex`.

Comment: You are right, its much better. I tried it right now. So can immediately get the value using `std::stoi(n,0,n)`. Thank you very much.